# Opencv face recogniser, confidence value of 0 by predict method python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to implement face recognition using Opencv's eigen and fisher faces in python and I am a complete newbie to both opencv and python. I have implemented it as far as I can understand from OpenCv's documentation but I think I am missing something.

What I am trying to do is first train the recognizer using a set of images. and then i read those images and predict them against the training set.
I am always receiving a confidence value of 0. Here is my code for training.

```
recognizer=cv.createEigenFaceRecognizer();
def getImageName(iPath):
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(iPath):
        for name in files:
            imgPath.append(os.path.join(path, name))    
    #imgPath = [os.path.join(iPath,imgid) for imgid in os.listdir(iPath)]
    faceId=[]
    imgId=[]
    #tmpId=1
    for imagePath in imgPath:
        dataImg = Image.open(imagePath).convert('L')
        faceNp=np.array(dataImg,'uint8')
        getId=int(imagePath.split('/')[1].split('s')[1])
        faceId.append(faceNp)
        imgId.append(getId)
        cv.imshow("training",faceNp)
        cv.waitKey(10)
    return faceId, imgId

faces, imgIds = getImageName("yalefaces")
recognizer.train(faces,np.array(imgIds))
recognizer.save('recognizer/trainingData.yml')
```

and for the recognizer

```
detector= cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
rec=cv2.createEigenFaceRecognizer()
rec.load('recognizer/trainingData.yml')
imgId=0
imgPath=[]
total = 0
corr = 0
def getImageName(iPath):
    global total
    global corr
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(iPath):
        for name in files:
            imgPath.append(os.path.join(path, name))
    faceId=[]
    imgId=[]
    tmpId=1
    for imagePath in imgPath:
        dataImg = cv2.imread(imagePath,cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
        total=total+1
        label,conf=rec.predict(dataImg)
        val=imagePath.split('/')[1].split('s')[1]
        print "predicted{}, confidence{}, val {}, path{}".format(label,conf,val,imagePath)
        if(int(label)==int(val)):
            corr=corr+1
        if(cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q') or cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('e')):
            break;

getImageName("yalefaces")
print total
print corr
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is a snippet of my output. Although the label and image number(val) match, the confidence value is always 0.

`predicted4, confidence0.0, val 4, pathyalefaces/s4/6.pgm
predicted15, confidence0.0, val 15, pathyalefaces/s15/1.pgm`

Any idea what am I missing or any code that had implemented fisher or eigen face in python. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Actually confidence=0 means the confidence is 100% i.e perfect match.Its the other way round.

```
conf=100-float(conf)
```

Try this and check out.

For additional info refer "Testing the Frame recognizer" section in:
http://hanzratech.in/2015/02/03/face-recognition-using-opencv.html

I hope it helps.

Comment: Only partly correct: while it is true that confidence=0 means a 100% match, you cannot say 100 - confidence because confidence is defined as DISTANCE i.e. it could be 500 or 5000 or 50000. It helps if you think of "confidence" as "error", see https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d65/classcv_1_1face_1_1FaceRecognizer.html#ab0d593e53ebd9a0f350c989fcac7f251

Comment: @cridgit **Confidence :
Associated confidence (e.g. distance) for the predicted label.** I guess for a classification task, it will be between 0 and 100 only.